# How to encode workbook to utf-8 in python?

Tags: python, excel, encoding, jupyter

On jupyter notebook in python 3, I want to save results in a `.xlsx` file using the class `workbook()`. I do not find an answer to how to encode it to utf8 so that I can save the file properly.

I have tried writing some lines I found online to solve it. However, they were used for other classes and did not help here.

```py
wb = Workbook('utf8',0)
ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
ws.title = "test"
ws.append([2])    
workbook_name = 'test'
wb.save(workbook_name + ".xlsx")
```

When I run the code I get the next message in the file generated:

```
Error! Path\test.xlsx is not UTF-8 encoded
Saving disabled.
See Console for more details
```

I would like it filled with the number `2` instead.

Comment: The message is about the path you want to save to (`workbook_name + ".xlsx"`), not the workbook contents. If you are on Python 3 I'm not sure what you can do, but do give details about your environment: You are on Windows, right?

Comment: Exactly, on Windows.

Comment: Seems like an OS integration issue; the question is whether jupyter, your excel class (which one???) or the combination of the two are responsible. Have you tried running this code from a command line Python? And have you checked that you can use a plain `open(workbook_name + ".txt", "w")` (and then write something to the file)? 

Depending on what you find when you do this, google (and search here) for path problems on Windows. I've seen similar questions come up before.